# If there is one column, is there no number in the shape form?

Tags: python

I split X and y to X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test.
When I printed each shape, I got the result as in the picture.
As you can see, I cannot see the column number of X_test and y_test. Because it said (4612,)
So, I have questions.

Q) If there is one column, is there no number in the shape form like this (4612,  ) or is there like this (4612,1)usually?

[image]

[image]

I tried to type `dataframe.shape` for another dataframe that has one column just in case, but I can see the one in the column area like this (76,1).

Comment: `print(type(VARIABLE))` to get the type of a variable

Comment: That function name is what I want to know!! Thanks a lot. 
Could you also let me know the answer to the second question?

Answer (score 0):

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test these are all numpy arrays or Pandas Series objects while the dataframe.shape that you mentioned below is for a dataframe.

That is the reason when you are printing x_train.shape it is showing it as (4611,) because it is a numpy 1D array.

Comment: Thank you! When I typed `print(type(y_train))`, it said <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.
So isn't it series?

Comment: Pandas Series and Numpy Array - Both behave similarly in this context because they are 1D arrays and not 2D arrays with 1 columns(like a dataframe). Any 1 dimensional data structure would give a response in the format (no of elements,) when shape is called upon it. I have modified the answer to also mention Pandas Series along with Numpy arrays